# Merging one database backup with another backup of database in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-restore

I am working on a project in which we have dummy records in the database for the development purpose and we have a testing environment where a copy of actual database is there.I want to merge the testing environment database in the development environment .I don't want to overwrite the development database as we have written integration /unit/browser test on the basis of dummy record and it would be a big task to modify test case for new data.
Please suggest some way to achieve it.

Comment: What parts of the database do you want to merge? schema, data, stored procs, functions, users?

Comment: I want to merge data. Data, stored procs, functions, users already exist on development enviroment

Answer (score 1):

You could you data compare softwares such as :

http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/datacompare/

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/